# Execute sudo Bash script as another user while being root

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, sudo, root

I am logged in as root and want to execute a Bash script with sudo permissions as another user.

This is the test Bash script in `/home/me/sudo.bash`:

```bsh
mkdir -p /etc/test # Creating an /etc directory to test permissions
echo "test $(whoami) $USER $HOME" > /etc/test/a.txt
```

The command I currently have (run from root, run for me):

```bsh
sudo --non-interactive --login --set-home --user=me \
sudo --non-interactive bash /home/me/sudo.bash
```

Contents of `/etc/test/a.txt`:

```
test root root /home/me
```

What I expected:

```
test me me /home/me
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The first `sudo` in that runs the given command as `me`, that command being another `sudo`, which runs the given command as `root`, which is `bash` with your shell script. What did you expect from the second `sudo`?

Comment: @muru Yes, this may be overcomplicated, but I didn't find a more simple way yet. The first `sudo` is for switching the user to `me`, the second `sudo` is for running the Bash script with elevated permissions, so I can create a directory in `/etc`.

Comment: sudo without --user always runs command as uid root, what he expects (use uid me and has sudo privilege) is not correct.

Comment: That makes no sense. "Elevated permissions" usually mean running as root; so you want your script to be run as `me` and `root` at the same time?

Comment: Why not just let your script create directory and file with root permission, and then change the owner to `me`, then use `me` to modify the content.

Comment: @muru Okay, I may have misunderstood the specific concept of `sudo`, sorry for that.

Another question: If `$(whoami)` and `$USER` aren't interesting for me because of the root context, how else do I know the current user that runs the Bash script? I could use `${HOME##*/}`, but that looks like a terrible hack.

Comment: If you want to know who ran `sudo`, there's the `SUDO_USER` environment variable: `sudo sh -c 'echo $USER $SUDO_USER'` => `root muru`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected, that `$(whoami)` will return "root", since it's running as root due to the second `sudo`.

Also, `$USER` will return "root" because `sudo` always sets that variable to the target user (which, again, is root on the second sudo.)

If you're interested in knowing which user invoked `sudo`, which would be "me" on the case of the second `sudo`, then look at the `$SUDO_USER` variable, which `sudo` sets to the user who invoked it.

See [SUDO_USER and USER](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.26/sudo.man.html#SUDO_USER) in the "Environment" section of the `sudo` man page.